# Pull and use JSON data from a URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

How can I pull and use JSON data using JavaScript?

For example, this [URL](https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor) has the following JSON:

```
{
   "id": "220439",
   "name": "Bret Taylor",
   "first_name": "Bret",
   "last_name": "Taylor",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/btaylor",
   "username": "btaylor",
   "gender": "male",
   "locale": "en_US"
}
```

How can I get this data into JavaScript variables?

I'm not looking to use Facebook API or anything dynamic right now, just getting JSON data from a static URL into JavaScript.

In PHP I could easily do this like:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$jsonObj = json_decode($contents);
echo "Name: ".$jsonObj->{'name'};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend jQuery's `$.getJSON()` method

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Live demo with your data here: http://jsfiddle.net/6ZeJ8/3/

Of course, you'll need jQuery to use this method, put this into the `<head>` of your HTML, should work just fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX) or a [script loader](http://dustindiaz.com/scriptjs) to fetch your JSON string, then [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON) the JSON string.