# Parsing JSON from URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, tumblr

I'm having trouble with getting the variables out of this JSON URL:

```
{
"meta":{
    "status":200,
    "msg":"OK"
    },      
"response":{
    "blog":{
        "title":"GideonPARANOID",
        "posts":5018,
        "name":"gideonparanoid",
        "url":"http:\/\/gideonparanoid.tumblr.com\/",
        "updated":1336919325,
        "description":"I study computer science at Aberystwyth, though I call Manchester home. I'm vegetarian, & take an interest in photography, gaming & cycling.",
        "ask":true,
        "ask_anon":true
        }
    }
}
```

I've been successful with using [a modified version of the JavaScript](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZeJ8/3/) given in the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352636/pull-and-use-json-data-from-a-url-with-javascript). I'm fairly unfamiliar with JSON, so I'm not sure about how to apply that properly - I've Googled for a good two hours, to no avail.

[My latest attempt](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZeJ8/10/) still doesn't deliver anything.

I'm using a sample API key from Tumblr's API given [here](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, `var result = JSON.parse(jsonString)`?

Answer (score 1):

try `JSON.parse(json_string)`.

Example:

```
var json_string = '{ "meta" : { "msg":"OK"} }';
var o = JSON.parse(json_string);
o.meta // {msg:'OK'}
o.meta.msg // 'OK'
```

And that's not a URL, that's JSON data.

Comment: That's invalid JSON. You need to put quotes around the keys, like this: `'{"meta":{"msg": "OK"}}'`

Comment: It was a demonstration, but thanks for pointing out. I will correct it, but it would be better to correct it yourself, I always do that (makes me feel better:)).